# Google maps closes immediately after opening

Tags: c#, android, google-maps, xamarin

I have a problem with the google maps. It supposed to show me my map but it opens the map and immediately closes it. The map is open in OnPickAPlaceButtonTapped but immediatly jumps to OnActivityResult closing the map.

```
    private void OnPickAPlaceButtonTapped(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        var builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
        StartActivityForResult(builder.Build(this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
    }

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST && resultCode == Result.Ok)
        {
            GetPlaceFromPicker(data);
        }

        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Comment: Why should that even matter @Stephen? Do you get anything indicating why in your Application Output window? Try also look in logcat.

Answer (score 0):

have you configured your app for using Google PlacesApi, if not refer (https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/start#Configure your app)
 and create API Key & also enable the Google Places Api on the console.

You can explore your logcat for error on these lines, just make sure to not select any filter in logcat